# Error trying to use module template and web.unified host sample

Tags: abp

I'm trying to execute web.unified host project based on a module template

1. `abp new sample.module -t module`. ABP CLI version 3.3.1
2. Restore: `dotnet restore`.Ok!
3. Build: `dotnet build`. Ok!
4. Adding a new entity in Domain (member.cs) and using [AbpHelper.GUI](https://github.com/EasyAbp/AbpHelper.GUI) to auto-generate all the code. Finish correctly!
5. Using web.unified to add migrations and update the database. Perfect!
6. Run web.unified web app `build run`
7. Open the app with the browser (chrome updated) and navigate to the new menu.
8. The index page for members (from the module web project) appears. Navigation and routes seem to be good. Cool!
9. But the browser console shows an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'member' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.js?_v=637403462413691892:5)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js?_v=637403457898237859:3534)
    at process (jquery.js?_v=637403457898237859:3602)
```

```js
$(function () {

    var l = abp.localization.getResource('Membership');

    var service = sample.membership.members.member; //<-- ERROR HERE sample.module.members is the namespace of entity in the module.
    var createModal = new abp.ModalManager(abp.appPath + 'Membership/Members/Member/CreateModal');
    var editModal = new abp.ModalManager(abp.appPath + 'Membership/Members/Member/EditModal');
...
```

Thanks so much for your input

Answer (score 1):

I got it!, The problem was [Auto API controllers](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/API/Auto-API-Controllers#auto-api-controllers).
The sample Hosts/*.web.unified project created using `abp new sample.module -t module` doesn't configure Auto API controllers for the module.

Adding this piece on your HostWebUnifiedModule.cs.
IMPORTANT: Add a reference to your module application project `MembershipApplicationModule`

```cs
[DependsOn(MembershipApplicationModule)]
public class HostWebUnifiedModule: AbpModule
{
    public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        Configure<AbpAspNetCoreMvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options
                .ConventionalControllers            .Create(typeof(MemberhsipApplicationModule).Assembly);
        });
    }
}
```

You obtain:

1. Auto API controller. Cool!, you can test using swagger.
2. The javascript library ([Dynamics JavaScript Library](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Dynamic-JavaScript-Proxies)) can now work correctly consuming the API.

Error gone!.