# New Module connected with a Host App but Route to the module pages gives me a 404 error

Tags: abp

I'm trying to get started with module development using [Abp framework](https://abp.io/), the potential of using the framework is huge with the community and the [abp.commercial](https://commercial.abp.io/) support if it's needed, but it's not always easy to up and running the application. Let me explain...

1. I have created a new module: `abp new sample.module -t module`. ABP CLI version 3.3.1
2. After that, I have added a new entity in Domain (member.cs) and using [AbpHelper.GUI](https://github.com/EasyAbp/AbpHelper.GUI) to auto-generate all the code.

My module works correctly using Hosts/*.web.unified test project. Well done! :).

*NOTE: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727855/error-trying-to-use-module-template-and-web-unified-host-sample/64730968#64730968) if you want to know how to solve a tricky issue for me at this point.*

3. Next, I have added assemblies one by one to the Host App. I have mapped:

Module.Application --> Host.Application

Module.Application.Contracts --> Host.Application.Contracts

Module.Domain --> Host.Domain

Module.Domain.Shared --> Host.Domain.Shared

Module.EntityFrameworkCore --> Host.EntityFrameworkCore

Module.HttpApi --> Host.HttpApi

Module.HttpApi.Client --> Host.HttpApi.Client

Module.Web --> Host.Web

4. Finally, I added Module Dependencies and Configurations, [following this post](https://community.abp.io/articles/reuse-abp-vnext-modules-to-quickly-implement-application-features-tdtmwd9w).

Restore, build, dotnet ef migrations, and *.HostApp.DbMigrator work like a charm and the database is updated based on the entities in the module. Cool!

But... when I run my Host App and click on the new module menu contributor the route doesn't work  but it seems to be correct based on the page structure of the module and it worked fine using Hosts/*.web.unified test project inside the module.

I tried several times with no lucky ‍♂️

Something is missing in the code that I cannot see.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Host application and Module are in different solutions. I was missing to include an assembly (Module.Web.Views.dll) into the Host web project.